# nested microdata properties with 3 levels

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'm trying to use micro data (using http://schema.org), but I have some difficulties with nested properties.

In short, I'm trying to have a product, that contains a review, which in turn contains an author. The 2 first levels are perfectly ok, but when I try to add an other to the review (of type "Person"), google tells me 2 things : that the other is missing for the review and that product doesn't accept author properties.

It seems that I fail to have the author within the review.

My code has a first level with :

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
```

Then later :

```
<span itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemprop="review">
    <p itemprop="reviewBody">myreview...</p>
    (author :<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <span itemprop="name">Name of the auhor</span>
    </span>)
</span>
```

Can any of you spot the mistake here ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You shouldn't use block `<p>` tag inside inline tag `<span>`

Comment: Here's a little tool to help you out with your errors: [https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the name for the product and didn't declare an item scope for review.

This is what you need to do:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
   <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemprop="review">
       <p itemprop="reviewBody">myreview...</p>
       (author :<span itemscope itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
                     <span itemprop="name">Name of the auhor</span>
                </span>)
   </span>
   <span itemprop="name">Product Name</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kunjan, 

You are absolutely right ! Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Fine. Please accept the answer if your problem is solved.